# How to check a dataframe consisting of a list of strings against a lookup dataframe and perform calculations?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, match, lookup

I have a dataframe `df1` that contains rows of tokenized strings:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data = {'tokens' : [['auditioned', 'lead', 'role', 'play', 
'play'], ['kittens', 'adopted', 'family'], ['peanut', 'butter', 'jelly', 
'sandwiches', 'favorite'], ['committee', 'decorated', 'gym'], ['surprise', 
'party', 'best', 'friends']]})
```

I also have a dataframe `df2` that contains single-word strings as well as a score pertaining to each word:

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data = {'word' : ['adopted', 'auditioned',
'favorite', 'gym', 'play', 'sandwiches'], 'score' : [1, 2, 3, 4, 5,
6]})
```

What is the best way to use `df2` as a sort of lookup "table" that I can also use to help perform calculations?

For each row in `df1`, I need to check whether any words exist in `df2`. If so, count the number of words found and store the result in a series called `word_count` (if a particular word appears more than once in `df1`, count each occurrence). Also, when a word in `df1` exists in `df2`, sum the score of that word with any other words found in a series called `total score`. The final output should look like `df3`:

```
df3 = pd.DataFrame(data = {'tokens' : [['auditioned', 'lead', 'role', 'play', 'play'], ['kittens', 'adopted', 'family'], ['peanut', 'butter', 'jelly', 'sandwiches', 'favorite'], ['committee', 'decorated', 'gym'], ['surprise', 'party', 'best', 'friends']], 'word_count' : [3, 1, 2, 1, 0], 'total_score' : [12, 1, 9, 4, None]})
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use:

```
d = df2.set_index('word')['score']

def f(x):
    y = [d.get(a) for a in x if a in d]
    return pd.Series([len(y), sum(y)], index=['word_count','total_score'])

df3[['word_count','total_score']] = df3['tokens'].apply(f)
print (df3)
                                          tokens  word_count  total_score
0           [auditioned, lead, role, play, play]           3           12
1                     [kittens, adopted, family]           1            1
2  [peanut, butter, jelly, sandwiches, favorite]           2            9
3                    [committee, decorated, gym]           1            4
4               [surprise, party, best, friends]           0            0
```

Answer (score 4):

### Approach 1

create a base dictionary to use for mapping within an apply

```
m0 = dict(df2.values)
m1 = lambda x: m0.get(x, 0)
m2 = lambda x: int(x in m0)
df1.assign(
    word_count=df1.tokens.apply(lambda x: sum(map(m2, x))),
    Total=df1.tokens.apply(lambda x: sum(map(m1, x)))
)

                                          tokens  word_count  Total
0           [auditioned, lead, role, play, play]           3     12
1                     [kittens, adopted, family]           1      1
2  [peanut, butter, jelly, sandwiches, favorite]           2      9
3                    [committee, decorated, gym]           1      4
4               [surprise, party, best, friends]           0      0
```

---

### Approach 2

create a new series that unwinds the words in `df1` but maintains the index values such that we can aggregate with count and sum.

```
idx = df1.index.repeat(df1.tokens.str.len())
s1 = pd.Series(np.concatenate(df1.tokens), idx)
s2 = s1.map(dict(df2.values)).groupby(level=0).agg(['count', 'sum'])
df1.join(s2.rename(columns=dict(count='word_count', sum='total_score')))

                                          tokens  word_count  total_score
0           [auditioned, lead, role, play, play]           3         12.0
1                     [kittens, adopted, family]           1          1.0
2  [peanut, butter, jelly, sandwiches, favorite]           2          9.0
3                    [committee, decorated, gym]           1          4.0
4               [surprise, party, best, friends]           0          0.0
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do

```
d=dict(zip(df2.word,df2.score))

helpdf=df1.tokens.apply(lambda x :pd.Series([d.get(y)for y in x ]))
df1['Total']=helpdf.sum(1)
df1['count']=helpdf.notnull().sum(1)
df1
Out[338]: 
                                          tokens  Total  count
0           [auditioned, lead, role, play, play]   12.0      3
1                     [kittens, adopted, family]    1.0      1
2  [peanut, butter, jelly, sandwiches, favorite]    9.0      2
3                    [committee, decorated, gym]    4.0      1
4               [surprise, party, best, friends]    0.0      0
```